# How to suggest pagebreak in tabularray longtblr?

Tags: tables, longtable, page-breaking, tabularray

I use large multirows and do not want it to break inside the multirows. I knew that the longtable package had functions for this, but I could not find many details about `longtblr` in the tabularray documentation.
However, I tried `\pagebreak[0-4]` to give a hint where to break, like with the longtable and it kind of works. My problem is, it makes a pagebreak no matter what number I give.
Any ideas why this is? Or should I simply not use tabularray for this? I like the beauty of using just one table package :)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\begin{document}

    \begin{longtblr}[
        caption= {In dieser Tabelle sind alle in der Modellierung verwendeten Steuerungsparameter  aufgeführt.},
        entry= {Steuerungsparameter},
        label={tblr:steuerungPara},
        ]{
            colspec = lcX[l],
        }
        \toprule
        Parameter & state & \SetCell[]{c}Erklärung \\
        \midrule
        SOC\_bat\_min   & \SetCell[r=11]{c}unveränderlich&Batterie  {soc} min.  Sollwert für penalty Faktor \\
        SOC\_bat\_max   & & Batterie  {soc} max. Sollwert für penalty \\
        SOC\_bat\_target    & & Batterie  {soc} Zielwert für penalty   \\
        SOC\_mhs\_off   & & Simulationsabbruch/ Sicherheit Restenergie       \\
        P\_fc\_min      & & Minimalleistung  {FC}    \\
        P\_fc\_max      & & Maximalleistung  {FC}             \\
        P\_bat\_min     & & Minimalleistung Batterie           \\
        P\_bat\_max     & & Maximalleistung Batterie          \\
        eff\_batt       & & Ladeeffizienz von Lithiumion Batterien nach PWC oder  Ng.2009        \\
        p1, p2, p3      & & Polynom 2. Grades Curvfitting Parameter \\ 
        s           & & Masseäquivalent Batterieleistung zu  \\
        \midrule  \pagebreak[4]
        P\_load         & \SetCell[r=3]{c}veränderlich & Summe aus Lastzyklus und PV-Leisutng\\
        SOC\_bat        &  & Aktueller Batterie  {soc}                                     \\
        SOC\_mhs        &  & Aktueller  {MHS}  {soc}                                     \\
        \midrule \pagebreak[0]
        fun\_val        & \SetCell[r=2]{c} Visualisierung & Funktionswert der Zielfunktion \\
        penalty\_bat        & &  {soc} abhängiger penalty Faktor\\
        P\_fc\_con      & \SetCell[r=2]{c} Ergebnis & Sollwert  {FC}\\
        P\_bat\_con         & & Sollwert Batterie\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{longtblr}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not use `\\*` instead of `\\ ` to disallow page breaks after this specific row?

Comment: yes thanks, did not think about that option, thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Command `\pagebreak` or `\nopagebreak` doesn't accept an optional argument in `longtblr` environment. But from your example, I guess what you want is to prevent breaking between any two `\midrule`s. Therefore you'd better replace some `\\`s with `\\*`s, as what @leandriis has commented.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[height=11cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {In dieser Tabelle sind alle in der Modellierung verwendeten Steuerungsparameter aufgeführt.},
  entry = {Steuerungsparameter},
  label = {tblr:steuerungPara},
]{
  colspec = lcX[l],
  rowhead = 1,      
}
  \toprule
    Parameter & state & \SetCell[]{c}Erklärung \\
  \midrule
    SOC\_bat\_min   & \SetCell[r=11]{c}unveränderlich&Batterie  {soc} min.  Sollwert für penalty Faktor \\*
    SOC\_bat\_max   & & Batterie  {soc} max. Sollwert für penalty  \\*
    SOC\_bat\_target    & & Batterie  {soc} Zielwert für penalty   \\*
    SOC\_mhs\_off   & & Simulationsabbruch/ Sicherheit Restenergie \\*
    P\_fc\_min      & & Minimalleistung  {FC}    \\*
    P\_fc\_max      & & Maximalleistung  {FC}    \\*
    P\_bat\_min     & & Minimalleistung Batterie \\*
    P\_bat\_max     & & Maximalleistung Batterie \\*
    eff\_batt       & & Ladeeffizienz von Lithiumion Batterien nach PWC oder  Ng.2009  \\*
    p1, p2, p3      & & Polynom 2. Grades Curvfitting Parameter \\*
    s               & & Masseäquivalent Batterieleistung zu  \\
  \midrule
    P\_load         & \SetCell[r=3]{c}veränderlich & Summe aus Lastzyklus und PV-Leisutng \\*
    SOC\_bat        &  & Aktueller Batterie  {soc}                                   \\*
    SOC\_mhs        &  & Aktueller  {MHS}  {soc}                                     \\
  \midrule
    fun\_val        & \SetCell[r=2]{c} Visualisierung & Funktionswert der Zielfunktion \\*
    penalty\_bat        & &  {soc} abhängiger penalty Faktor\\*
    P\_fc\_con      & \SetCell[r=2]{c} Ergebnis & Sollwert  {FC}\\*
    P\_bat\_con         & & Sollwert Batterie\\
  \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]